# Problems With PHP Path Prefix when Compiling from Source

Tags: php, makefile, apache2.2, centos6.5

I'm following these two articles to install multiple versions of PHP while compiling from source:
http://www.sitepoint.com/run-multiple-versions-php-one-server/
http://www.phpinternalsbook.com/build_system/building_php.html

I'm trying to install PHP 5.6 into /opt/php56 (a directory I've created) however, when I run ./buildconf and then run the following, PHP overwrites itself.

> > How I compile PHP:

```
./buildconf (does its thing)...

./configure \
--prefix-dir=/opt/php56/ \
--disable-opcache \
--enable-bcmath \
--enable-calendar \
--enable-ftp \
--enable-gd-native-ttf \
--enable-libxml \
--with-libxml-dir=/opt/xml2/ \
--enable-pdo=shared \
--with-pdo-mysql=shared \
--with-pdo-sqlite=shared \
--enable-sockets \
--prefix=/usr/local \
--with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs \
--with-curl=/opt/curlssl/ \
--with-freetype-dir=/usr \
--with-gd \
--with-imap=/opt/php_with_imap_client/ \
--with-imap-ssl=/usr \
--with-jpeg-dir=/usr \
--with-kerberos \
--with-libdir=lib64 \
--with-mcrypt=/opt/libmcrypt/ \
--with-mysql=/usr \
--with-mysql-sock=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock \
--with-openssl=/usr \
--with-openssl-dir=/usr \
--with-pcre-regex=/opt/pcre \
--with-pic \
--with-png-dir=/usr \
--with-xpm-dir=/usr \
--with-zlib \
--with-zlib-dir=/usr \
--enable-soap \

 make 
 make install (which installs everything to /usr/local/bin, despite the set prefix on ./configure).
```

> > What happens when I run the following:

```
root ~>># which php
/usr/local/bin/php

root ~>># sudo -u foo which php
/usr/bin/php
```

What am I doing wrong with the --prefix ? The last install I did, I ran ./configure --prefix=/opt/php56/ and this too didn't take.

Comment: I don't have the answer to your question but I wanted to make sure you knew there were backports available. https://webtatic.com/packages/php56/

Comment: Thanks, however I followed the settings for adding that repo and whenever I tried yum install php56w, yum said there was no package available.

Comment: Did you run yum update before the install? It should work.

Comment: This is what I get when I run yum update:
http://termbin.com/bbuo

Comment: For some reason you're missing webtatic. You should see something like: `* webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com`

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I was not telling the compiler where I wanted my directories. Case in point:

```
./configure \
--prefix=/opt/php56 \
--bindir=/opt/php56/bin \
--libdir=/opt/php56/lib \
--sysconfdir=/opt/php56/etc \
--includedir=/opt/php56/include/php \
--mandir=/opt/php56/php/man \
```

... the rest has been left off for brevity.